# Django Transactions: How to run extra code during rollback?

Tags: django, transactions

Imagine you have a `User` model in your web app, and that you need to keep this user in sync with an external service via an API. Thus, when you create a user locally, you need to create it remotely as well.

You have all your operations under `transaction.atomic()` and you try to keep all your 3rd-party API calls **after** the atomic block, which is reasonable.

But, a system being a system, it grows in complexity until the point you have some really hard to remove 3rd-party calls within an update call.

That said, is there a way to extend Django's transaction mechanism, kind of adding some callback functions, like `rollback.add_callback(clean_3rdparty_user(user_id=134))`?

That way I can guarantee that all necessary rollback actions are taken and my system is in sync?

Comment: have a look on this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94780/transaction-atomic-with-continuations

Answer (score 4):

The author of Django's transaction hook code has [this to say](https://django-transaction-hooks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) about why there is `on_commit()` but not `on_rollback()`:

> A rollback hook is even harder to implement robustly than a commit hook, since a variety of things can cause an implicit rollback. For instance, your database connection was dropped because your process was killed without a chance to shutdown gracefully: your rollback hook will never run.

Since rollbacks are typically triggered by an exception, a simple approach is to just catch any exceptions and run your undo code there.

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        # Do database stuff
        # Do external stuff
except:
    # We know the database stuff has rolled back, so...
    # Undo external stuff
    raise
```

This is not particularly elegant. I agree with the following from the same source:

> The solution is simple: instead of doing something during the atomic block (transaction) and then undoing it if the transaction fails, use on_commit to delay doing it in the first place until after the transaction succeeds. It’s a lot easier to undo something you never did in the first place!

But it sounds like you already agree with that as well.